# Easy formula for ultrarelativistic bremsstrahlung?

Tags: large-hadron-collider, relativistic-jets

I am very curious if an easy calculable formula for the bremstrahlung radiation of deeply relativistic, charged particles exists, if they are moving on circular orbit:

$P(E,m_0,Q,r)=?$

...where

- $P$ is the power of the Bremstrahlung radiation;
- $E$ is the total kinetic energy of the particles (we are in deeply relativistic case, thus $E\gg{m_0}c^2$);
- $m_0$ is the total rest mass of the particles;
- $Q$ is the total charge of the particles;
- and $r$ is the radius of the orbit.

If a such clean, trivial formula doesn't exist, a link were also okay, where it can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radiation from an ultrarelativistic ($v \approx c$) particle on a circular path is called [synchotron radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation#Velocity_.E2.8A.A5_acceleration%3a_synchrotron_radiation). The total power radiated from such a particle is $$P = \frac{e^2 a^2}{6\pi \epsilon_0 c}\gamma^4$$
where $a$ is the acceleration and $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor, $\gamma^2 = 1/(1-v^2/c^2)$.

Comment: And what is the ultrarelativistic acceleration? $\omega^2r$?

Comment: good question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66839/10531

Comment: For circular motion $a = v^2/r = \omega^2 r$.

Comment: This is not taking into account magnetic field or the particles charge (both important factors), this formula does not look correct to me...